# Lossless PDF rotation

Tags: python, pdf, ubuntu, rotation, lossless

is there a way to rotate a PDF 90 degrees **losslessly**, with Python or using the command line?

I'm looking for a REAL rotation, not just adding a "/ROTATE 90" inside the PDF, because afterwards I have to send the PDF via Hylafax and it looks like that it ignores those commands.

I tried with ImageMagick's *convert* but the quality of the resulting PDF is quite low.

(Python 2.6.2, Xubuntu 9.04)

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [pdfjam package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pdfjam) there is a shell script `pdf90` which does the rotation via pdflatex.

Comment: Woa, 256Mb of dependencies.. X-) I'll try it anyway, thanks :)

Comment: Oh yeah :) a LaTeX distribution typically needs several hundred MB of hard disk space

Comment: The rotation looks nearly lossless though.. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

The best resolution you will normally obtain from a standard fax machine is about 200dpi; standard faxes are about 100dpi.  If you need your faxed documents to work with an artitrary fax machine you can't go above this.

Ergo, rendering your PDF to a 100 or 200dpi bitmap and rotating it 90 degress should work as well as anything.  Various ghostscript based tool chains can do the rendering.  Alternatively, there are a number of PDF and postscript based tools that can do this type of manipulatiion (e.g. [PDF2PS](http://orion.math.iastate.edu/burkardt/g_src/pdf2ps/pdf2ps.html) and [psutils](http://www.tardis.ed.ac.uk/~ajcd/psutils/)) directly off the PDF.